# How to get the count value using $lookup in mongodb using golang?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Using aggregation I am joining two collections of mongodb using golang. The result is seems like below:-

OUTPUT:-

```
{
"response": {
    "code": 1,
    "api_status": 1,
    "message": "Success",
    "total_record": [
        {
            "_id": 1,
            "author_name": "mohit",
            "category": 232,
            "content": "This is the content",
            "date_time": 1524632713,
            "excerpt": "This is a  short text",
            "image": "pic.jpg",
            "resultField": [
                {
                    "_id": 6,
                    "comment": "this is a least comment",
                    "comment_on": 1524644601,
                    "email": "puneet@bookingkoala.com",
                    "name": "puneet",
                    "post_id": 1,
                    "reply_to": 1524644601,
                    "status": 1
                },
                {
                    "_id": 7,
                    "comment": "this is a least comment",
                    "comment_on": 1524647808,
                    "email": "puneet@bookingkoala.com",
                    "name": "puneet",
                    "post_id": 1,
                    "reply_to": 1524647808,
                    "status": 1
                }
            ],
            "status": 0,
            "tags": "this",
            "title": "how to do the code"
        },
        {
            "_id": 2,
            "author_name": "mohit",
            "category": 232,
            "content": "This is the content",
            "date_time": 1524632713,
            "excerpt": "This is a  short text",
            "image": "pic.jpg",
            "resultField": [
                {
                    "_id": 8,
                    "comment": "this is a least comment",
                    "comment_on": 1524648059,
                    "email": "puneet@bookingkoala.com",
                    "name": "puneet",
                    "post_id": 2,
                    "reply_to": 1524648059,
                    "status": 1
                }
            ],
            "status": 0,
            "tags": "this",
            "title": "how to do the code"
        },
        {
            "_id": 3,
            "author_name": "puneet",
            "category": 2,
            "content": "this is content",
            "date_time": 1524641086,
            "excerpt": "this is excerpt",
            "image": "pic.jpg",
            "resultField": [],
            "status": 1,
            "tags": "go",
            "title": "how to do the code"
        }
    ]
 }
}
```

This **output** is taken by the below code of golang:-

```
mongoSession := config.ConnectDb()
collection := mongoSession.DB(config.Database).C(config.BlogCollection)
pipeline := []bson.M{
    bson.M{"$match": bson.M{}},
    bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{"from" : "comment", "localField" : "_id", "foreignField": "post_id","as": "resultField" }},
}
fmt.Println(pipeline)
pipe := collection.Pipe(pipeline)
resp := []bson.M{}
err = pipe.All(&resp)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Errored: %#v \n", err)
}
fmt.Println(resp)
if err != nil {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.FailureCode,
        config.FailureFlag,
        config.FailureMsg,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
} else {
    response = ResponseControllerList{
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessFlag,
        config.SuccessMsg,
        nil,
        resp,
    }
}
```

Issue is:- I need only `count` of the `data` **not** the `data`. Means in the output as shown above there is the `resultField` in which data is show but I only need the `count` value like:- `"resultField":[2]` but it is showing the data. How can I will get the count values of the data in output. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your aggregation actually returns all `comment` documents in the `resultField` field, which implicitly contains the number of results, it's a slice of which you can check the length in Go using the builtin `len()` function.

Since you only need the length (number of `comment` documents), that's why you want to only retrieve the size of this array. For that purpose you may use the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage to replace the `resultField` array with a number being the length of this array.

```
pipe := c.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "comment",
            "localField":   "_id",
            "foreignField": "post_id",
            "as":           "resultField",
        },
    },
    {
        "$addFields": bson.M{
            "resultField": bson.M{"$size": "$resultField"},
        },
    },
})
```

Note that `$addFields` stage is equivalent to a `$project` stage that explicitly specifies all existing fields in the input documents and adds the new fields. Available only since MongoDB version 3.4.