# mgo example for populate method

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am new to GoLang & MongoDB. I am trying to understand their relation using mgo. However , I am unable to find a suitable example on how to fetch referenced objects from mongo in Go using mgo. I have heard about populate method but no idea how mgo uses it. Can anyone throw light on the same?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB provides `$lookup` to perform left outer join.  Below is an example using mgo.

```
func TestLookup(t *testing.T) {
    var err error
    uri := "mongodb://localhost/stackoverflow?replicaSet=replset"
    dialInfo, _ := mgo.ParseURL(uri)
    session, _ := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
    c := session.DB("stackoverflow").C("users")

    pipeline := `
    [{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "addresses",
            "localField": "address_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "address"
        }
    }, {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$address"
        }
    }, {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": "$name",
            "address": "$address.address"
        }
    }]
     `
    var v []map[string]interface{}
    var results []bson.M
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(pipeline), &v)
    if err = c.Pipe(v).All(&results); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, doc := range results {
        t.Log(doc)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad, but in general if you want to fetch "referenced" object with a single query, you have to use MongoDB's [Aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), specifically the [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage.

The aggregation framework can be used from `mgo` with the [`Collection.Pipe()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Pipe) method.

For an example, see [Get a value in a reference of a lookup with MongoDB and Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48163774/get-a-value-in-a-reference-of-a-lookup-with-mongodb-and-golang/48174216#48174216).

Some more examples:

[How to get the count value using $lookup in mongodb using golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018938/how-to-get-the-count-value-using-lookup-in-mongodb-using-golang/50020168#50020168)

[Only return the looked up document with Mongo and Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944814/only-return-the-looked-up-document-with-mongo-and-golang/50945740#50945740)

Comment: Let me narrow it down .Basically lets say , my user model contains address_id field with value as bson.objectId. And the address lies in a different collection with same bson.objectId. Now how can i fetch the user object along with the complete address data in a single response ?? I hope it helps ..